# How do I get over a problem getting methodID in jni

Tags: android, hashmap, java-native-interface

I'm trying to invoke a java method from JNI.

For that I did the following:

This is my java class

```
data class MyJavaClass(var keyId: String = ""): HashMap<String,Any>(){
     fun getSpecialObjects(): HashMap<String, Array<SpecialObject>>{
             val result = HashMap<String, Array<SpecialObject>>()
             forEach { (k, v) ->
                try {
                   val vJson = gson.toJson(v)
                   val item: ArrayList<SpecialObject> = gson.fromJson(vJson, type)
                   result[k] = item.toTypedArray()
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                  //this is OK, i'm filtering the right values
             }
            }
            return result
     }
    }
```

This is my wrapper class

```
    class Wrapper {
              companion object {

              // Used to load the 'native-lib' library on application startup.
             init {
                System.loadLibrary("wrapper")
             }
           }
         external fun doSomething(objects: Array<MyJavaClass>): HashMap<String,Any>
     }
```

This is my jni definition

```
  extern "C" JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL
Java_com_mypackagename_wrapper_Wrapper_doSomthing(JNIEnv *env, jobject jobj, jobjectArray arrayOfMyJavaClass ) {

    auto objectArrayLength = env->GetArrayLength(arrayOfMyJavaClass);
    std::string className = "com/mypackagename/path/to/MyJavaClass";
    jclass clzz = findClass(env, className);
    jfieldID keyIdFieldId = env->GetFieldID(clzz, "keyId", "Ljava/lang/String;");
    jmethodID  getSpecialObjectsMethodID = env->GetMethodID(clzz, "getSpecialObjects", "()Ljava/util/HashMap;");

    for (int i = 0; i < objectArrayLength; i++) {
        auto object = env->GetObjectArrayElement(arrayOfMyJavaClass, i);

        auto key = env->GetObjectField(object, keyIdFieldId);
        auto map = env->CallObjectMethod(object, getSpecialObjectsMethodID); <-- it falls here
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

my code falls on the following line:

```
auto map = env->CallObjectMethod(object, getSpecialObjectsMethodID);
```

I ran **javap -s MyJavaClass**  and received the following result:

```
public final class com.mypackagename.path.to.MyJavaClass extends java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object> {
  public final java.lang.String getKeyId();
    descriptor: ()Ljava/lang/String;

  public final void setKeyId(java.lang.String);
    descriptor: (Ljava/lang/String;)V

  public final java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String, com.mypackagename.path.to.SpecialObject[]> getSpecialObjects();
    descriptor: ()Ljava/util/HashMap;

  public final boolean isValid();
    descriptor: ()Z

  public com.mypackagename.path.to.MyJavaClass();
    descriptor: ()V

  public java.lang.Object getOrDefault(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object);
    descriptor: (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;

  public final java.lang.Object getOrDefault(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
    descriptor: (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;

  public boolean containsKey(java.lang.String);
    descriptor: (Ljava/lang/String;)Z

  public final boolean containsKey(java.lang.Object);
    descriptor: (Ljava/lang/Object;)Z

  public java.lang.Object get(java.lang.String);
    descriptor: (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;

  public final java.lang.Object get(java.lang.Object);
    descriptor: (Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;

  public java.lang.Object remove(java.lang.String);
    descriptor: (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;

  public final java.lang.Object remove(java.lang.Object);
    descriptor: (Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;

  public boolean remove(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object);
    descriptor: (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Z

  public final boolean remove(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
    descriptor: (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Z

  public java.util.Set getEntries();
    descriptor: ()Ljava/util/Set;

  public final java.util.Set<java.util.Map$Entry<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> entrySet();
    descriptor: ()Ljava/util/Set;

  public java.util.Set getKeys();
    descriptor: ()Ljava/util/Set;

  public final java.util.Set<java.lang.String> keySet();
    descriptor: ()Ljava/util/Set;

  public java.util.Collection getValues();
    descriptor: ()Ljava/util/Collection;

  public final java.util.Collection<java.lang.Object> values();
    descriptor: ()Ljava/util/Collection;

  public int getSize();
    descriptor: ()I

  public final int size();
    descriptor: ()I
}
```

However my code falls because it claims the methodID for **getSpecialObjectsMethodID is null**.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is all your error checking? You should check the return values after every JNI call, as well as check for exceptions. Also, your Kotlin doesn't doesn't look like it would even compile (what's a `HasMap`? what are you calling `forEach` on?).

Comment: forEach is called on the "this" object, which is a HashMap

Comment: Can we assume that all the typos in package and class names were made in the process of anonymizing your code? ("mypackgename/path/of" vs "mypackagename.path.to") Does `clzz` contain a useful value? What about `keyIdFieldId` or `getSpecialObjectsMethodID`

Comment: @Botje yes the typos = name reductions, and yes clzz does contain the correct class, the field keyId is retrieved without issues

Comment: Does it also contain a useful value? Because `javap` insists your class does not have a `keyId`, only getters and setters for it. There is no point in proceeding if keyIdFieldId or getSpecialObjectsMethodID are null.

Comment: @Botje: The backing field for `keyId` is private. `javap` does not show private members by default.

Comment: @Michael Oh. That just leaves getSpecialObjectsMethodID then.

Comment: @Botje both ```clzz``` and ```keyId``` contain useful values, yet ```getSpecialObjectsMethodID``` is **null**. I don't understand why it is null.

Comment: Are you sure that the method name isn't being obfuscated by ProGuard/R8? Anyway, I suggest that you reduce this down to a complete minimal example that you can post the full code for.

Comment: proguard not yet implemented in this project

Comment: Just to rule out Proguard/R8: Can you log the result of `new MyJavaClass("abc").getSpecialObjects().hashCode()` somewhere in your code ? That should prevent the method from getting removed. If that works then you have to add `MyJavaClass` to a magical "keep" list in your project.